# How do I extract an image out of a PDF using Preview for Mac?

Tags: macos, pdf, preview, graphics, image-processing

I have a PDF that is from a scanner that is only an image (no text).

Is there any way to extract the image out of the PDF in Mac Preview?
Or is that the same thing as converting the PDF to an image?

Comment: Use `cpdf -extract-images`. See https://community.coherentpdf.com

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It is not possible to extract just the image from a PDF in Apple Preview.app. However, here are two alternative ways:

### 1. Crop the PDF to the image.

Go to the Menu Bar -> Tools and select Rectangular Selection. Then:

Drag a box around the image in question and then press Command+K which will crop to the selected area. Then you can save.

### 2. Screenshot the image.

Press Command-Shift-4 and then drag a box to select the image - when you let go, it will automatically save to your screenshots location. (By default this is **Desktop**.)

These might not be the most effective ways for batch converting, but they will work.

Comment: When I try to click and drag to create the selection on the PDF to crop, it just selects the whole PDF and it turns blue. There's no dashed square like if I was trying to crop a regular image. Do you know why this happens? -- I thought about making screenshots of it but I made the image very high resolution, so I would have to zoom in and take a lot of screen shots and then stitch them back together :/

Comment: why don’t you just [export the page of your PDF directly from Preview](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/preview/prvw1012/mac) as an image?

Comment: That works. Per my question, I wasn't sure if there was any way to specifically take the image out of the PDF vs converting it to an image (or if the processes are the exact same).

Comment: @Wimateeka If these methods are good enough for you, then they are easy and quick.  But they are making a new representation of the image, not an unchanged extraction of the image.

Comment: @Wimateeka I updated my answer to show how to get the dashed line,.

Comment: the export of a pdf page from Preview offers the option to define the resolution in dpi/ppi. Another option would be to open the PDF in e.g. Vectornator, Inkscape & Co. and drag&drop it to the finder. If the page is already an image, this will suffice - if it is a vector the Preview export from a vector- to a pixel-based format defining the resolution gives you the fastest solution anyway.

Comment: PeterNielsen, in one of the answers below @Gilby mentions that pure extraction isn't possible. If you add this fact to you answer I will accept it since your alternative solutions focus on using Mac Preview.

Comment: Sure, it's done

Answer (score 11):

### Method 1

The [Poppler](https://poppler.freedesktop.org) PDF rendering library provides `pdfimages` (amongst other useful utilities) which will extract individual images from a PDF to an output specification e.g.:

`% pdfimages -png input.pdf output`

will produce a set of numbered output images in PNG format. The default output formats are PBM or PPM for mono and colour images respectively. The `-j` flag will extract embedded JPGs as JPG but other files will usually be output as PPM if the default is not changed. See the manpage for more options.

Poppler can be installed from Homebrew `% brew install poppler`

### Method 2

While not actually extracting embedded images in a PDF as usable files, `convert` from the [ImageMagick](https://imagemagick.org) suite will output each page as an image file, given a suitable incantation. Note the example from [SU](https://superuser.com/questions/633698/convert-pdf-to-jpg-images-with-imagemagick-how-to-0-pad-file-names):

`% convert -density 600 foo.pdf foo-%02d.jpg`

(The `%02d` is to specify an incrementing number suffix in each output file.)

There are many other command line options to `convert`. With a suitable density you can crop the resulting images if required with little loss of resolution.

The ImageMagick download page has numerous install options for the package, including Homebrew and MacPorts.

Usually with these sort of issues you will need to think outside the box of the common tools such as Preview, there's usually always something open-source that will do the job.

Comment: Poppler's `pdfimages` is indeed the best solution. Simple and fast. And its `-all` option lets you extract all images at once in a single command. And it is also available in Linux (eg. `apt install poppler-utils` in Ubuntu).

Answer (score 0):

I have always used [File Juicer](https://echoone.com//filejuicer/) for extracting all the individual components of PDFs.  It works fine for a PDF with a single image inside.

[File Extractor](https://macdaddy.io/File-Extractor/) is cheaper (particularly from the App Store), but I have never used it.

I expect there are other GUI apps, as well as command line utilities which will do the job for you.

Comment: Does this mean that you cannot do it in Preview? This is the tool I was asking about specifically.

Comment: @Wimateeka I am assuming you want to extract the exact image as made by the scanner - same resolution, size, compression and metadata. You can't do that in Preview.

Comment: @Wimateeka What you can do in Preview - besides the already mentioned export - is to drag the whole page with the image from the thumbnail bar to e.g. the finder or directly into e.g. an open Pages document. you have to masked the image - but this way you end up with the original embedded resolution and color depth of the image.

Comment: @Gilby if this is the case then I will accept it as an answer with a list of other options to instead export rather than extract.

Answer (score -1):

If it's a standard PDF file then you can save the image from the right-click option.

Comment: When I right click the PDF while in Mac Preview, I don't see that as an option. The options I get are "Search with Google", "Copy", "Automatically Resize", "Zoom In", "Zoom Out", "Actual Size", "Single Page", "Single Page Continuous", "Two Pages", "Two Pages Continuous", "Next Page", "Previous Page", and "Services". Services is a menu and those options are "Add to Music as a Spoken Track", "Convert Text to", "Simplified Chinese", "Convert Text to Traditional Chinese", "Open", "Search With Google", "Show in Finder", and "Show Info in Finder" :/

Comment: There is an easy way to download all the images from the PDF I found the online tool. You can go to pdfcandy site and upload your pdf to get all the images. I feel it's easy and time-saving.

Comment: The usual risk with online tools like this is that you loose control over your PDF files...